# Social networking websites build in ethereum blockchain have instant block time while in the main ethereum network it ranges from 10-20 seconds why?

Tags: dapp-development, dapps

I'm new to blockchain actually and I have an idea of a social app and want to build it in blockchain because of complete transparency and privacy-friendly and so.

But I feel that it might piss off the users if it takes much time to update or post content.

Comment: Hi there. Welcome to Stack Exchange. Can you clarify what your question is? Can you point us to which social networking sites are able to update instantly? If they're not running on the main network, are they running on a test network or framework?

Comment: @RichardHorrocks telegram is the most common. And others which are mentioned here- https://hackernoon.com/6-social-media-powered-by-blockchain-fdc41d16cb12

Comment: @testbeta I doubt that telegram uses Ethereum, although it is possible for a social network site to use a side-chain or another off-chain to achieve faster response times.

Comment: @Ismael thanks for your response. I was all looking for this particular answer whether it is worth learning blockchain for my social startup idea or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're most likely seeing the UI simply update it's state immediately, with a callback writing to the blockchain behind the scenes

Comment: Hmm yeah, that's a possibility. Anyways thank you for the response.